# Disable Snippet of HTML IF User is On iPad or Mobil Device?

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari, code-snippets

I'd like to disable a snippet of HTML on iPads and mobile devices. This part of my site doesn't work on small screens... Any way to do it?

Thanks,

Tara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript solves your problem, look this:

```
var isIpad = navigator.platform.indexOf("iPad") != -1,
isIphone = navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1,
isIpod = navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1;
```

Comment: Just an FYI ...for me! Does this also work for Windows Mobile and Windows 7 Phone devices? All this **i** stuff makes me think it is *Apple* aware only.

Comment: I don't know but you can alert navigator.platform to see what windows'll show, let us know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `User-Agent` header to detect if your user is coming from iPhone/iPad/MobileDevice. Then just don't output that piece of HTML.

You can use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) database to check for mobile devices capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Would you give me an example of the User-Agent header I would use to block that snippet for iPad Safari?

Also, how to I select which piece of HTML I want to be dis-activated on that condition?

Thanks

Comment: @Tara: Perhaps you could query for the maximum screen resolution. Disable your extra anytime your page width and height are under, say, 640x480. Just a thought.